# Is there a way to view version history of a column attribute changes?

Tags: column, versioning

This question is not about version history of changes made in an item record but changes made to the columns or attributes within the list settings. Like for example when someone adds a new attribute or field in a SharePoint form. I haven't found a method to view that through the SharePoint site.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the audit log report to determine who is taking what actions with the columns.

1. Configure audit log settings for the site collection.

   Site settings ->  Under Site Collection Administration, click Site collection audit settings -> On the Configure Audit Settings page, in the Documents and Items and List, Libraries, and Site sections, select the events you want to audit, and then click OK.
2. View the audit log report.

   Site settings ->  Under Site Collection Administration, click Audit log reports -> Run a custom report and enter relevant information. Specify the report to log “Editing content types and columns”.

Reference:

[Configure audit settings for a site collection.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-A9920C97-38C0-44F2-8BCB-4CF1E2AE22D2)

[View audit log reports.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-audit-log-reports-b37c5869-1b47-4a82-a30d-ea20070fe527)

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2010 by the way. And I think the steps you have suggested do not apply to SharePoint 2010. I have rephrased the question to make it more understandable.